# Tailwind css &:hover feature is not being applied (nextjs application)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Here's my file structure

```
|--src
|  |--components
|     |--Menu
|        |--index.js
|        |--index.module.css
|--tailwindcss.config.js
```

In my `index.module.css` file I have a piece of code:

```css
.iconWrapper {
  @apply cursor-pointer flex justify-center items-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md;

  &:hover,
  &.active {
    background-color: theme("colors.text2");
  }
  .icon {
    color: theme("colors.text1");
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

but for this I'm getting thrown an error

```
Syntax error: Selector "&:hover,
  &.active" is not pure (pure selectors must  local class or id)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Well I don't think next CSS module supports nesting selector yet.  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/62644 Hopefully it will soon. For now you need to either use a Post CSS plugin or just separate them such as `.iconWrapper:hover`